# re.sub() not replacing value in an expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to replace `v__a` with `z3Sigs` but the following code doesn't do that.

```
import re
SigOnDecision = ['v__a', '__Vdly__v__a']
x = "(1 & v__a) == 0"
for signs in SigOnDecision:
    p = "{}".format(signs)
    y = re.sub(p, "z3Sigs", x)
print y
```

This code prints the original value of `x` only i.e. `(1 & v__a) == 0`
Can anyone point out the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't modify `y`. You only replace the value of `x`:

```
y = re.sub(p, "z3Sigs", x)
```

Modify `x` instead:

```
x = re.sub(p, "z3Sigs", x)
```

Or set `y` to `x` and modify `y`:

```
y = x

for signs in SigOnDecision:
    y = re.sub(p, "z3Sigs", y)
```